# Doing a vlookup in vba

Tags: vba

I have 2 workbooks.  In the first workbook (which contains the macro) I am trying to do a vlookup to determine if the value strCompany exists in column A of the second workbook (tmp_workbook).

I get the following VBA error: 
"Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class)"

```
Dim company_exists_in_list As Variant
Dim main_workbook As Workbook, tmp_workbook As Workbook

strCompany = main_workbook.Sheets("Input ID").Cells(10 + i + b * (j - 1), 3).Value 

company_exists_in_list = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(strCompany, tmp_workbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A100000"), 1, False)
```

Comment: If `strCompany` does not exist in `Column A` you will get an error. Maybe try using `.Find` as it more gracefully handles the case where no match is found

Comment: Remove the `.WorkSheetFunction` part.  This will allow the error to pas into the variable.  Then test the variable for the error.

Answer (score 0):

`VLookup` used in one row, only return the same value. You can use `CountIf` to know if the value exist.

```
company_exists_in_list =Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(tmp_workbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A100000"),strCompany)
```

If the value is different to 0 then the company exists.